# Why won't getElementsByClassName select all of my elements?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to to hide multi elements with same class name in my webview app

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"> 1 </div>
<div class="col-md-2"> 2 </div>
<div class="col-md-2"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

I tried getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll it's just hide first element

```html
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
"var head = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-2')[0].style.display='none'; " + "})()");
```

Comment: `[0]` in `document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-2')[0]` selects the first element!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this its simple grap all elements and add the style attribute

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"> 1 </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> 2 </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> 3 </div>
</div>

<script>

    document.querySelectorAll(".col-md-2").forEach(function(e){
        e.style.display='none';
    });

</script>
```